# Wireless is disabled by hardware switch on a Dell Latitude

Tags: wireless, intel-wireless

I have the same problem in 11.10, and it occured just before I installed 12.04, thought by remove and complete install 12.04 the problem wolud be gone , but no still there also in 12.04

i have a dell latitude with a intel 5100 wireless

it was working perfect before , dont know what happend or what i did 
..........
also the sudo commands where do you enter those , by alt f2 ?? or in the bios ??

Comment: i know it has to do with the airplain mode but how to fix it

Comment: Have you tried pressing Fn button and then the button with a little radio antenna on it? Something like Fn-F8, it's different on different laptops.

Comment: tried FN with each F button no use, but thanks ;-)... also i read things about run sudo rfkill list all and then sudo rfkill unblock all but where you have to type this they dont say, also hear about download dell biosupdate , but no internet , i dont really run commandos, i didnt do that ever, yeah maybe in windows 95 in dos ...i am so nooby to ubuntu

Comment: Some laptops have a separate button which turns wifi on or off. What's the laptop model, btw?

Comment: If you want to experiment with those `rfkill` commands - open Terminal (Alt-Ctrl-T or just type its name after clicking on the top-left button) and enter the commands there. It will require your user password. `rfkill` docs say it can't unblock devices blocked via a hardware switch anyway...

Comment: thanks sergey, i have a dell latitude e5500, so no use to use rfkill because u say it cant unblock hardwareswitch devices ?

Comment: if i press altctrl t it opens my trash bin LOL  ...you mean top left the dash home.. if i enter commands like sudo rfkill it finds nothing

Comment: rob, I mean click Dash home button and type "terminal" there. It'll open a window where you'll be able to enter commands. Also, try to find the hardware switch on the keyboard - I found some pics of the laptop on the Dell website but they're too small

Comment: type terminal first finally thanks sergey, great ... sudo rf kills says 0:dell wifi: wirelessLAN Soft blocked yes hard blocked yes 1: wireless lan soft blocked no hard blocked yes ( i think the second is the wireless usb adopter i tried but thats removed)

Comment: also the command sudo rfkill unblock all didnt do anything

Comment: `rfkill` says the device is hard-blocked. See my answer below to locate the hardware switch. Just press the button...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your laptop's User Manual:

- http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/systems/late5400/en/qrg/qrg_en.pdf

Wifi hardware switch is #18 on the diagram on page 7 :)

Try turning it on and off.

Comment: Sergey you are the best !! i feel a litte stupid haha, never knwe this button was there and it so small and out of sight i never would have find out, let me send you a virtual box of chocolate, bottle of wodka , whatever you like LOL problem solved case closed :-)